# Does System.Action keep a weak reference to the owner of the method?

Tags: c#, delegates

Is a weak reference used or will failing to remove all references to a System.Action keep the owner of the method it is calling alive due to this reference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All delegates hold a *strong* reference to both an object instance (when not referencing a static method) and a method to execute on that instance.  Keeping the delegate alive will keep the object (if there is one) that the delegate invokes its method on alive.